# Load an Image in separate textarea(other than TinyMce) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, textarea

ok, I have a snippet at jsfiddle, I have two textarea's, right one is a tinymce editor and on the left textarea I need to load the images onclick of a particular option in a dropdown.

Every thing is self explanatory in the fiddle. I need help in loading the image in the textarea.

Can somebody point me in a right direction. I have commented the paths of five image files in fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/TgZXL/73/

Thanks

Comment: You want to load the image URL that's in the non tinyMCE textarea in to the tinyMCE, is that right?

Comment: Alex I want to load the image in the left hand side textarea and not in the tiny MCE textarea. Please see the comments between me and Thariama, if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked using your js-fiddle code. Just place this on top of your html code like i did in http://jsfiddle.net/TgZXL/75/   :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function create_img(source){
    //console.log(source);
    ed = tinymce.get('second');
    ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img src="'+source+'"/>')
}
</script>

<table>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><select name="sel" id="sel" onchange="create_img($('#first').val())">
```

Comment: I want to images the load in the left hand side textarea and not on the tinymce editor textarea, that is on the right hand side.

Comment: i do not understand for what reason you need the tinymce editor on that page (?)

Comment: I am sending an email to  a bunch of people, The tinyMCE editor will be used to write a customized message  depending on the left hand side image

Comment: so, what you want to insert exactly into the left textarea? (you cannot place a real image there cause a textarea contains text only), but you could place the html text of an image there if this it what you want

Comment: ok, I knew that would cause an issue, If I place a 1px image there(with dimensions of textarea) and then on click of the options in dropdown change the src attribute of 1px image to my required images. How would that change my fiddle. I think this is the only alternative, but I am not sure how to accomplish this with jquery

Comment: where do you want to place the 1px-image?

Comment: Where I have right hand area textarea, I mean exactly below my drop down list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3634/discussion-between-mike-and-thariama)

Comment: though it didnt solve my problem, but I am choosing this as accepted answer, coz u put in the efforts. You are the only tinymce guy here

Comment: thanks, but i am not the only tinymce guy here, there is Brett Henderson for example